# Import Contact in Active Directory ( Windows Server 2008 R2 )

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Which tool do you use to update or import large numbers of contacts into Active Directory?

Currently I use Solarwinds user import tool for bulk importing users into AD, but it doesn't work for importing contacts.

Comment: A question that asks `Which tool do you use to...` falls under the category of 'Product, service, or learning material recommendations' which is considered [offtopic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the below product, it is also free
http://www.dovestones.com/active-directory-contact-import

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bulk-import contacts by using [`csvde`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327620).

Comment: Hi Ansgar, Thanku for ur reply,can we use csvde to modify entry, i want to modify or append some data to already exist contact

Comment: For modifying existing contacts better use [`dsmod`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755470%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) or [`ldifde`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755456%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Creating Bulk Users in Active Directory Using [PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitgupta/archive/2012/02/06/creating-bulk-users-in-active-directory-using-powershell.aspx)

Step-by-Step Guide to Bulk Import and Export to Active Directory

with **LDIFDE**  utility and other ways that article links [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727091.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

LDIFDE, CSVDE, dsadd/dsmod, new-ADUser, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

As the guys mentioned above one method is CSVDE, this would be the easiest way to import attributes into Active Directory objects.

Can you clarify when you say 'contacts' you mean you would like to import the 'contact' attribute of an object? or do you want to import a new user itself?

By default the CSVDE tool is used to export user account from a directory, you must specify the -i switch to export the objects. To export all the directory information you can use this command;

```
csvde -f export.csv
```

Here is a good tutorial http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/simplify-admin-tasks-by-exporting-active-directory-data-with-csvde/427